# Update serializer if queryset exists

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

If the queryset exists, I would like to update the existing instance instead of creating a brand new one.

The way I currently have it raises an error saying unexpected kwargs are being passed if the serializer is trying to update.

Could someone please help me do this?

```
class APNSDeviceViewSet(DeviceViewSetMixin, ModelViewSet):
    queryset = APNSDevice.objects.all()
    serializer_class = APNSDeviceSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        queryset = APNSDevice.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        if queryset.exists():
            # update serializer to contain new information
            serializer.update(
                device_type=self.request.data.get('device_type'),
                registration_id=self.request.data.get('registration_id'),
                device_id=self.request.data.get('device_id'))
        else:
            # create a new model instance
            serializer.save(
                user=self.request.user,
                device_type=self.request.data.get('device_type'),
                registration_id=self.request.data.get('registration_id'),
                device_id=self.request.data.get('device_id'))
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Peering into the Django Rest Framework code, specifically serializers.py, it's clear you're providing incorrect parameters for the `update()` method.  Its signature is not like the `save()` method's signature.  It expects as a first argument the model instance, and as a second argument a dictionary containing the data.  So in your case it would look something like this:

```
instance = queryset[0]
serializer.update(instance, {'device_type': self.request.data.get('device_type'), 'registration_id': self.request.data.get('registration_id'), 'device_id': self.request.data.get('device_id')})
```

Comment: It gives me a key error for u'user'. Do you know why that is happening?

Comment: post your new code. I don't understand where you're using the 'user' key.

Answer (score 0):

All you want is a base queryset that is restricted to the current user. 
This is performed by [the filters](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-the-current-user) in an elegant and simple way.

On a side note you should not invoke serializer.update by yourself. It's called by the serializer through the serializer.save method. The difference between update et create is that the serializer is instantiated with a Model's instance for updates.

Comment: In my urls, I have the following: `APNSDeviceViewSet.as_view({'post': 'create'}),`. This will always have it create, rather than seek for an update method. Is there a way to change the parameters here to have it check for a current serializer, otherwise create a new one?